# Trying to load json data from txt file into python variable

Tags: python, json

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
     dat2 = file.read()

post2 = {
        "id": 5,
        "method": "set",
        "params": [
            {
                "data": [
                     dat2
                    ],
                "url": "/config/url"
            },
            ]
        "session": sessionkey,
        "verbose": 1
        }
```

Data from the file I am trying to read looks as so...`{"name": "IPS10-Host1","type": "ipmask","subnet": ["","255.255.255.255"],"dynamic_mapping": null}, {"name": "IPS10-Host2","type": "ipmask","subnet": ["","255.255.255.255"],"dynamic_mapping": null},`
I am trying to read this data and insert into a variable to put it into `post2` for a request. What I have tried so far includes: reading the file and replacing `null` with `None` so python can read it as well as stripping all of the whitespace. I have tried using `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()`, but nothing seems to work. After the data is placed into `dat2`, it gets inserted into `post2` as `'{data}'` instead of `{data}`. I have been stuck on this part of my code for the longest time now and would appreciate and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `json.load`?

`json.loads` loads the JSON data from a string, hence the s at the end